# Azure Media Service - Video can not play on Android Phone with browse

Tags: android, google-chrome, azure, video, media

I upload a video(.mp4) to the Azure Media Service. The Encoding setting is H264 Adaptive Bitrate MP4 Set 1080p.

I play the video on Iphone with Chrome, it works well.

But I play it on Android with Chrome, it can't play.

I try to encode it another way, such as Playback via html5, but the result is that it can't be published.

Want to know how to solve it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share a bit more details on how you are trying to play it back on Chrome? Which URL did you pass to Chrome?

Depending on the version of Android phone you are using there can be a lot of complex concerns to deal with.

1. Some versions of Android differ significantly by vendor or OEM.  For example a Nexus 5 does not even have H.264 codecs installed on it, so it won't play back the video.
2. Some devices supported an early version of the HLS protocol, while most modern ones support MPEG-DASH now.  You have to have a player that is intelligent enough to choose the right protocol (URL) for delivery. Azure Media Player attempts to make the right decision for you based on your Azure Media Services streaming URL.  Try it out on this page here to see if it plays back for you: http://ampdemo.azureedge.net/

Finally, open the developer tools in Chrome (Ctrl-shift-I) and check the Console for Error messages or error codes that could help indicate why playback is failing (if you are able to debug via desktop that is)